# Magento2 - How to customise Magento modal styling?

Tags: magento-2.1, modal-popup

How to give css to **Magento modal popup**.

I want to edit the title styling and other styling on the popup.

Comment: in your custom popup or magento default pop up ??

Comment: I used magento modal widget in my custom theme.